# substr SQl function

Tags: sql, oracle, substring

I have a problem in parsing my last name and first name in a table. My code:

```
SELECT value, 
       substr(value,instr(value,' ',1),instr(value,' ',2)-2) last_name,
  FROM (SELECT 'Matt Ryan, QB' value 
          FROM dual);
```

If  I write `'Andrew Luck, QB'` it parses properly the last name.  But when I write `'Matt Ryan, QB'` it parses just two letters from the last name. I identify it by white space. I don't understand what can be wrong here.

```
'Matt Ryan, QB'
'Andrew Luck, QB'
```

Comment: what is the problem!?? what do you want from the query?

Comment: @Farhęg it won't be a wild guess to assume he wants to extract the last name ;)

Comment: @alfasin my comment was before any edit on question

Comment: @Farhęg in that case, my apologize! I arrived after it was already clear.

Comment: @alfasin, no problem that's fine never mind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please consider using regular expression. I think this should solve your problem.

```
SELECT value, 
    REGEXP_SUBSTR(value,
                '\w+\s+(\w+\s+\w+|\w+),',1,1,NULL,1) last_name
    FROM ( 
    SELECT 'Matt Ryan, QB' value FROM dual 
    );
```

Check this [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/9eecb/1632/0)

Comment: Jack, If this works for you. Can you please accept my answer.

Comment: This seems to be the best answer, I checked all with samples from hr.employees (Oracle [HR](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e10831/installation.htm#COMSC001) schema). 
But something is wrong with 'Lex De Haan, QA' ;-)

Comment: I just updated the Reg Exp. This should work for  'Lex De Haan, QA'  as well. Please refer to the fiddle.

Comment: For me it looks OK, already upvoted your answer, but I'm not Original Poster, he's the judge here;-)

Comment: Thanks a lot , sorry for the delay .

Answer (score 1):

You're misusing the index parameter that you're passing to `instr`, plus you should remove the comma that comes after "last_name". Try:

```
SELECT value, 
substr(value, instr(value,' ')+1, instr(value,' ',instr(value,' '))-1) last_name
FROM ( 
  SELECT 'Matt Ryan, QB' value FROM dual 
);
```

**[Link to fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/9eecb/1586)**

Comment: Or sorry this stil doesnt work for me . But reg_exp work perfec.

Answer (score 1):

The occurrence parameter of [`INSTR`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions068.htm) is the fourth parameter, so you have to use

```
instr(value,' ', 1, 1) -- first space
```

and

```
instr(value,' ', 1, 2) -- seconds space
```

The third parameter of [`SUBSTR`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions162.htm) is the number of characters to extract. This is the position of the second space minus the position of the first space - minus one for the comma:

```
instr(value,' ', 1, 2) -instr(value,' ', 1, 1) -1
```

So all in all it's:

```
SELECT value,
      substr(value, instr(value,' ', 1, 1),
                    instr(value,' ', 1, 2) -instr(value,' ', 1, 1) -1) last_name
 FROM (SELECT 'Matt Ryan, QB' value 
         FROM dual);
```

Check this Fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/9eecb/1617).